# In a reboot/Shutdown event, would SNMP trap be sent before the event occurrence or after that?

Tags: snmp, monitoring

When a device is getting ready to shut down or reboot, Would the SNMP agent send the trap notification to the destination host before the shutdown/reboot event, or after that?

What's the general rule for other events like fan or temperature events (if there's any)?

Thanks

Comment: I Don't think there is no generic answer here, it would all depend on the vendor's implementation.

Comment: @TeunVink Thanks Teun. What's the more common situation in the industry then? is there any? Wasn't this concept important enough to be set in the protocol's principles?

Comment: In my experience, most devices will send the shutdown just before shutting down. There aren't any rules or protocols. SNMP is just a protocol for transferring information in a standardized format, the way it is deployed is up to the vendor.

Comment: @TeunVink Thanks for sharing the experience. It's reasonable. I wish I could vote up your comment.